# I am getting virtual machine error while running my brownie fundme contract

Tags: web3.py, ganache, smart-contract-wallets, brownie, solidity-0.6.x

```
PS E:\brownie_fund_me> brownie run scripts/fund_and_withdraw.py --network ganache-local
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\fund_and_withdraw.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run   
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\fund_and_withdraw.py", line 22, in main
    fund()
  File ".\scripts\fund_and_withdraw.py", line 9, in fund
    entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee()
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\multicall.py", line 115, in _proxy_call
    result = ContractCall.__call__(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1729, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, block_identifier=block_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1533, in call    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
VirtualMachineError: revert
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any ganache instance running on any port

You can do so by running

```
lsof -i:8545
kill -9 {pid#1} {pid#2} etc..
```

If above doesn't fix the issues, try reinstalling ganache-cli, but do not run it on any session. I don't know why this fixed the same issue for me, but it worked like a magic.